# Selected value for dropdownlistfor in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a ViewBag selectlist in Edit action and set the value to be selected as:

```
ViewBag.Doors = new SelectList(
    new[]
    {
        new {ID = 1, Name="1-Door"},
        new {ID = 2, Name="2-Doors"},
        new {ID = 3, Name="3-Doors"},
        new {ID = 4, Name="4-Doors"},
        new {ID = 5, Name="5-Doors"},
        new {ID = 6, Name="6-Doors"},
        new {ID = 7, Name="7-Doors"}
    },
    "ID", "Name", advert.Doors);
```

But in the view the value for the dropdown is not selected by default.

My view code is:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Doors, (SelectList)ViewBag.Doors, "--Select--")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Doors)
```

The property Doors will be numeric 1,2,3,..

Comment: Do you want `advert.Doors` or `model.Doors` to be selected?  Usually when you use `DropDownListFor` you want the selected value to be the one from the view model.

Comment: what is the value for `advert.Doors`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### How will I do it using Annonymous type in ViewBag ?

**Overload**

[image]

**Controller Action Method**

```
public ActionResult DropDownListFor()
{
    ViewBag.Doors = new SelectList(
                        new[]
                        {
                            new {Value = 1,Text="1-Door"},
                            new {Value = 2,Text="2-Door"},
                            new {Value = 3,Text="4-Door"},
                            new {Value = 4,Text="4-Door"},
                            new {Value = 5,Text="5-Door"},
                            new {Value = 6,Text="6-Door"},
                            new {Value = 7,Text="7-Doors"}
                        }, "Value", "Text", 7);
    return View();
}
```

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownList("Doors")
```

### How will I do it using SelectListItem?

**Action Method**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DropDownListFor()
{
    List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();

    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Action", Value = "0" });
    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Drama", Value = "1" });
    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Comedy", Value = "2", 
                                                             Selected = true });
    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Science Fiction", Value = "3" });
    ViewBag.MovieType = items;

    return View();
}
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DropDownList("MovieType")
}
```

### How will I do it using View Model?

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Id, Model.DDLList, "Please select");
}
```

**Action Method**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DropDownListFor()
{
    return View(new Models.Dropdown());
}
```

**View Model**

```
public class Dropdown
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> DDLList
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<SelectListItem>() 
            { 
                new SelectListItem
                { 
                    Text = "1-Door", 
                    Value = "1", 
                    Selected = true
                },
                new SelectListItem
                { 
                    Selected = false, 
                    Value = "2", 
                    Text = "2-Door"
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it really work with `DropDownListFor`? It doesn't seem to.