# How to get drop down value in Controller in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I Bind dropdown using list of string using recursive function
My dropdown have value like 
Home 
Home>> Kitchen
Home>> Kitchen>> ABC

and i want to Same dropdown value ABC in database

This is my View code

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Createnewproduct";
}
<h2>
    Create new product</h2>
<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Createnewproduct", "ProductAdmin", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "sendFileForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Category
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownList("Test", new SelectList(ViewBag.ListOfDisciplines, Model))
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Product Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="ProductName">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Product Description
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="ProductDescription">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Product long Description
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name=" ProductlongDescription">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    UPC
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="UPC">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    SKU
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="SKU">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Stock
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="Stock">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Weight
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="Weight">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Height
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="Height">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Image URL
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="width: 100%;" id="Imageupload" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
</div>
```

and my controller like this

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Createnewproduct(FormCollection form)
        {

        }
```

when i see my FormCollection value there i did not find dropdown value , all other value properly find in FormCollection

Please help me where i did the mistake in this code

---

```
 public ActionResult Createnewproduct()
    {
        List<Category> categorylist = _Listofcategory();
        var parentcate = categorylist.Where(c => c.ParentCategoryId == 1).ToList();
        List<String> categoryList = new List<string>();
        string prefix = ">>";
        foreach (var item in parentcate)
        {
            prefix = item.CategoryName;
            Setchild(prefix, item, categorylist, categoryList);


        }

        ViewBag.ListOfDisciplines = categoryList;
        return View();
    }


    private void Setchild(string prefix, Category model, List<Category> listcategory, List<string> catStrings)
    {
        var childs = listcategory.Where(x => x.ParentCategoryId == model.CategoryId).ToList();

        catStrings.Add(prefix);
        if (childs.Count > 0)
        {

            foreach (var child in childs)
            {
                catStrings.Add(prefix + ">>" + child.CategoryName);
                var subchild = listcategory.Where(c => c.ParentCategoryId == child.CategoryId).ToList();
                if (subchild.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var subsubchild in subchild)
                    {
                        catStrings.Add(prefix + ">>" + child.CategoryName + ">>" + subsubchild.CategoryName);

                        var subsubsubchild = listcategory.Where(c => c.ParentCategoryId == subsubchild.CategoryId).ToList();
                        if (subsubsubchild.Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (var subsubsubsubchild in subsubsubchild)
                            {
                                catStrings.Add(prefix + ">>" + child.CategoryName + ">>" + subsubchild.CategoryName + ">>" + subsubsubsubchild.CategoryName);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }


            }

        }

    }
```

This my List of Category how to use in View model.

Please let me know

Comment: Is your DD working properly on client side (I mean showing correct data )?

Comment: **[I m assuming your DropDownList is not getting populated properly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18534522/2015869)**

Comment: **[You should pass View Model to Post Action Method instead of Form Collection.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17203239/2015869)**

Comment: Yes DDl working properly and all value are populate properly

Comment: @user1035814 Would you like to do this job by using ViewModel?If so I can give you a help.

Comment: Hi Sampath , How to do using ViewModel . Can you guide me ?

Comment: Are you really sure you have to send your form data as multi-part ?

Comment: @user1035814 If its just a way of data display on the ddl,then you have to format the data before bind it to the ViewModel's of ddl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use below mentioned sample code for your scenario as well.Here I have used ViewModel.

**Domain Models :**

```
 public class Product
    {
        public Product() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(); Created = DateTime.Now; }
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        
        public virtual ProductCategory ProductCategory { get; set; }
    }

 public class ProductCategory
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
```

**View Model :**

```
public class ProductViewModel
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "required")]
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        
        public int SelectedValue { get; set; }
    
        public virtual ProductCategory ProductCategory { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Product Category")]
        public virtual ICollection<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }
    }
```

**Action Methods :**

```
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult AddProduct() //generate view with categories for enter product data
        {
            //for get product categories from database
            var prodcutCategories = Repository.GetAllProductCategories();

            //for initialize viewmodel
            var productViewModel = new ProductViewModel();
            
            //assign values for viewmodel
            productViewModel.ProductCategories = prodcutCategories;

            //send viewmodel into UI (View)
            return View("AddProduct", productViewModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddProduct(ProductViewModel productViewModel) //save entered data
        {
            //get product category for selected drop down list value
            var prodcutCategory = Repository.GetProductCategory(productViewModel.SelectedValue);
            
            //for get all product categories
       var prodcutCategories = Repository.GetAllProductCategories();

            //for fill the drop down list when validation fails 
             productViewModel.ProductCategories = prodcutCategories;

            //for initialize Product domain model
            var productObj = new Product
                                     {
                                         ProductName = productViewModel.ProductName,
                                         ProductCategory = prodcutCategory,
                                     };

            if (ModelState.IsValid) //check for any validation errors
            {
                //save recived data into database
                Repository.AddProduct(productObj);
                return RedirectToAction("AddProduct");
            }
            else
            {
                //when validation failed return viewmodel back to UI (View) 
                return View(productViewModel);
            }
        }
```

**View :**

```
@model YourProject.ViewModels.ProductViewModel        //set your viewmodel here

 <div class="boxedForm">
  
@using (Html.BeginAbsoluteRouteForm("add", new { action = "AddProduct"},FormMethod.Post }))
         {
             <ul>
                     <li style="width: 370px">
                           @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProductCategories)
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedValue,new SelectList(Model.ProductCategories, "Id",
                                             "CategoryName"),"-Please select a category -")
                           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProductCategory.Id)
                    </li>
                    <li style="width: 370px">
                  @Html.CompleteEditorFor(m => m.ProductName, labelOverride: "Product Name")
                  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProductName) 
                    </li>
            </ul>
                    <div class="action">
                        <button class="actionButton" type="submit">
                            <span>Save</span></button>
                    </div>
         }
   </div>
```

**Final Output**

[image]

Comment: Hi Sampath , i think its should be work for me  . i will update you later first i will try to implement this .. Thanks for ur help

Comment: @user1035814 OK sure.Take your time and let me know If you have any issues.If so, I will help to you. :)

Comment: Thanks you Sampath :) Really u r good understanding of MVC . i am just beginner of MVC and learn from music store in MVC , and want to create eCommerce site .. Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: @user1035814 Glad to hear that it helped.If you need more help,Plz let me know.You can find my details through StackOverFlow Profile (
http://stackoverflow.com/users/1077309/sampath).                      Good Luck !

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `ViewBag.ListOfDisciplines` is a `List<Discipline>` and your Discipline class is:

```
public class Discipline {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

If you have a List of strings you could transform it in a Array of anonymous in the controller side

```
ViewBag.ListOfDIsciplines = from d in ListDisciplines select new { Id = d, Name = d };
```

In your view you should use

```
@Html.DropDownList("Test", new SelectList(ViewBag.ListOfDisciplines, "Id", "Name"), "-- Select here --")
```

Comment: Hi Roger, Discipline is the List of string so i think its not working .Please see my code Below . which i bind in dropdown

Comment: @user1035814, Ok, what is the generated View HTML code for your combo ?

Comment: <select id="Test" name="Test"><option>Home1</option>
<option>Home1</option>
<option>Home1</option>

</select>

Comment: @user1035814, as you can see, your options has no value, thats the source of your problem, try using my approach and insted of using list of string, you use a LINQ instead (updated response)

Comment: No Rozar option have the value Home1 , Home1 .... which is populate in my dropdowon list

Comment: @user1035814, You have passed the Model class to your SelectList contructor, Home1 might be the name of your View, thats the reason you have that name repeatedly for each of your options, bielive me, use my approach.

Comment: Hi Sampath, data is coming but not the above format.dropdown populate the value computer , desktop but i need computer >> desktop