# Saving the value from dropdown to entity framework MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to save values from dropdownlist to the database using MVC 5 + Entity Framework. The values for the dropdownlist are taken from the DB (and displayed), but when I am saving the web entry then the value of the `OrderSourceList` is null and the `OrderSourceId` = 0
**Model**

```
public class OrderFullModel
{
    [Display(Name = "OrderSource")]
    public IList<SelectListItem> OrderSourceList {get;set;}

    public int OrderSourceId { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Create() //this is returning the right dropdownlist
{
    var orderSources = _repository.All<OrderSource>().OrderBy(m => m.NameRu).ToList();
    ViewBag.MyOrderSources = new SelectList(orderSources, "Id", "NameRu", 0);
    return View();
}
```

**View**

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.OrderSourceList)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.OrderSourceList, (SelectList)ViewBag.MyOrderSources)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `DropDownListFor` is a helper that expects an expression for the value in the list you want to display/set, so:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.OrderSourceId, (SelectList)ViewBag.MyOrderSources)
```

Currently you're asking for a dropdown to set the value of a list.

From the [Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownListFor(
this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList)
```

> expression: 
>   An expression that identifies the object that contains the properties to display.
>
> selectList:
>   A collection of SelectListItem objects that are used to populate the drop-down list.

Comment: then I am getting   Message=The ViewData item that has the key 'OrderSourceId' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.

Comment: I would suggest you have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18549424/3175307) for an example of how it all fits together. It seems odd that you have a list of SelectListItems in your model, should that not be a list of OrderSources?

Comment: @sidux, You get that error because `ViewBag.MyOrderSources` is `null`, most likely because you did not reassign the value in the POST method if you returned the view because `ModelState` was invalid.

Comment: @sidux, But why are you assigning the `SelectList` to `ViewBag`? Your model already has a property named `OrderSourceList` so it should be `var model = new OrderFullModel(); model.OrderSourceList = orderSources; return View(model);` in the controller and `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.OrderSourceId, Model.OrderSourceList)` in the view.