# Adding id to mvc4 dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

This is my code:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m=> m.IsCurrentlySmoking, new{ onchange="RiskChange(this)", id="IsCurrentlySmokingLeftDrp", SelectList(new List<Object>{
                            new { value = 0, text = "Fortsatt rökning"},
                            new {value = 1, text = "Minskat rökning"},
                            new {value = 2, text = "Röker ej"},
 }, "value", "text", 0)}
```

The code worked fine untill i added the id to it. Now i get the error: CS0746: Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

What is wrong with the code? I have added id to other mvc form elements that way and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: **[this answer should help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507086/selected-value-for-dropdownlistfor-in-mvc4/18534522#18534522)**

Answer (score 2):

You messed-up the `SelectList` and `htmlAttributes` order. Just change it like this, it will work:

```
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.IsCurrentlySmoking, new SelectList(new List<Object>{
                        new { value = 0, text = "Fortsatt rökning"},
                        new {value = 1, text = "Minskat rökning"},
                        new {value = 2, text = "Röker ej"}, 
       }, "value", "text", 0), new { onchange = "RiskChange(this)", id = "IsCurrentlySmokingLeftDrp" })
```