# Setting Html Attribute overloads on @Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

**ViewModel**

```
public class ProjectEditViewModel
{
    public Project Project { get; set; }
    public Client Clients { get; set; }
    public PageElementsViewModel PageElements { get; set; }
    public SelectList ClientList { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<int> ClientListId { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
ProjectEditViewModel peVm = new ProjectEditViewModel
  {
    Project = projectRepo.Projects.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.ProjectId == projectId),
    ClientList = new SelectList(clientRepo.Clients.Select(_ => 
                 new { id = _.ClientId, name = _.Name }).ToList()),
    ClientListId = clientRepo.Clients.Select(_ => _.ClientId).ToList(),
    PageElements = new PageElementsViewModel
    {
      PageTitle = "Edit Project",
      TitleIcon = "entypo-pencil",
      BodyClass = "project-edit"
     }
};
```

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Project.ClientId, Model.ClientList,
                      new { value = Model.ClientList,@class="drop-item" })
```

I just want to be able to add a class and a value to the current drop down list values. The current Model.ClientList is returning a value so it is not like the drop down list is not being popluated.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703573(v=vs.118).aspx

> htmlAttributes Type: System.Object
>
> An object that contains the HTML attributes to set for the element.

**is Model.ClientList not a system object?**

I get the feeling i a missing something very fundamental in my understanding.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selected value for dropdownlistfor in mvc4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507086/selected-value-for-dropdownlistfor-in-mvc4)

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the part of assigning a new `value` this way, by editing `ProjectEditViewModel` class.

Since you are creating a SelectList, you can create a `SelectListItem` with a `value` Property instead of an anonymous type:

```
ProjectEditViewModel peVm = new ProjectEditViewModel
{
    Project = projectRepo.Projects.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.ProjectId == projectId),
    ClientList = new SelectList(clientRepo.Clients.Select(_ => 
                     /* NEW: typesafe instead of anonymous type */
                     new SelectListItem 
                     { 
                         Value = _.ClientId, 
                         Text = _.Name 
                     }).ToList()),
    ClientListId = clientRepo.Clients.Select(_ => _.ClientId).ToList(),
    PageElements = new PageElementsViewModel
    {
      PageTitle = "Edit Project",
      TitleIcon = "entypo-pencil",
      BodyClass = "project-edit"
     }
};
```

As for your original code: You are assigning a value alright, but it is a whole selectList all over again, instead of a single simple string value like `"1" or "Mastercard"`, which of course will fail.