# DropDownList Conversion from C# to VB

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having a hard time converting C# to VB.

I can get its counterpart to work in C#.

I got this from: 
[Selected value for dropdownlistfor in mvc4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507086/selected-value-for-dropdownlistfor-in-mvc4)

In View: General.vbhtml

```
@Html.DropDownList("DST1");
```

In Controller: GeneralController.vb

```
Function ddl() As ActionResult
    Dim items As New List(Of SelectListItem)()

    items.Add(New SelectListItem() With {.Text = "Yes", .Value = "1"})
    items.Add(New SelectListItem() With {.Text = "No", .Value = "2"})
    ViewBag.DST1 = items
    Return View()
End Function
```

Comment: What is the problem, are you getting any error or ?

Comment: Maybe this [link](http://converter.telerik.com/) can help you.

Comment: Have used this [link](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) and always work fine for me.